# Why aren't my Follow Me links working?

Tags: plugins, widgets, code

I've been working o my website and I just noticed that most of the links from my Follow Me plugin are broken.  The feed link works fine, but everything else leads to a 404.  I can see what's wrong with the URL - my site address and "%20" gets put in front of every link and there are some additional problems.  What I can't figure out is why this is happening or how to fix it.  I have never touched the plugin code and every other link on my site works fine.  I tried reentering the links and deleting and reinstalling the plugin.  The problem persists.  I'm self taught in HTML and CSS, so the plugin code is a little beyond me.

[Here's my site](http://www.inkandpixelclub.com).  The Follow Me plugin is at the top of the sidebar on the right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't reproduce - all links look and work fine for me.

Comment: I just did a little checking and it appears to be somewhat browser specific.  The links work fine on Safari, but both Camino and Firefox have the problem I was describing.  That's all the browsers I have, so I don't know how it works on any others.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, see it in Firefox (Opera seems to fix it on the fly).

The %20 you are seeing is encoded space character. First thing to check would be to verify that there are no unwanted spaces in form you use to setup links.

Also could you please add link to specific plugin you use? Quick search gets several similarly named in official repository.

**Update**

What version of plugin are you using? It doesn't seem to be latest one. Older versions (I looked at 2.0 which seems closer to what you have live) seems to have possible markup issues because of new lines stuffed in links attributes where they shouldn't be.

Comment: I checked in the form itself and while it does have the somewhat annoying feature of putting "http://" at the front of the form (kind of useless, since I just copy and paster the whole url), I've been careful to make sure there aren't any double https or leftover space.

Comment: Developers site for the plugin is:

Comment: http://www.ignitesocialmedia.com/tools/follow-me/  (Sorry, still getting use to the fact that hitting return posts the comment.)

Comment: WP plugins page claims I have 3.0.1 which looks like the latest version.  Not sure why my code would not reflect that.  (Sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  Spent all of yesterday shoveling snow.)

Comment: @InkAndPixelCLub then I am not sure, I didn't spot any obvious issues with latest version. I'd try completely deleting and reinstalling plugin.

Comment: @Rarst Deactivated and delted the plugin via the plugins page.  Reinstalled and activated it and found that my old links were immediately restores.  I guess the links must be kept somewhere other than the plugin folder?  Anyway, I tried deleting all of the links, deleting the plugin again, and reinstalling it again.  Problem persists.  I'm starting to think I'd be better off finding a different follow me plugin.

Comment: @InkAndPixelCLub links are probably stored as options/settings in database, but this seems more like markup issue. Personal opinion - plugin does seem messy inside and I won't use it myself (but I am very picky in general about this stuff).

Comment: @Rarst I've decided to give up.  Picked out another social media follow me plugin and while I miss everything being in a nice compact bar that expands to show all the links, the new plugin looks fine and the links work.  Anyway, thanks for trying to sort this out for me.  I really appreciate it.